# Object array data source for FlatList empties when used as renderItem

Tags: reactjs, react-native

this is an extension of an earlier question now debugged to realize it's a different issue. I have an object array that looks like this when logged to console:

[image]

I now want to use this object array to display a list using `FlatList` component. in my state constructor, I set a variable to `itemList` which takes in objects generated from my `listenForMusic` function using `this.setState()`:

```
class VideoFeed extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //this.dataRef = database.ref("music");
        this.state = {
            itemList: null,
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.listenForMusic(); 
    }

    listenForMusic(){
        var dataRef = database.ref("music");
        let items = [];
        dataRef.orderByChild("date").on('child_added', (snap) => {
            items.push({
                videoURL: snap.val().youtubeURL,
                title: snap.val().title,
                thumbnail: snap.val().thumbnail
            });
        });
        this.setState({ itemList: items })
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.itemList);
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.itemList}
                    renderItem={({item}) => { console.log(item); return (<Text>{item.videoURL}</Text>) }}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I have that console.log in my render function and I see the image I posted above, but when I try and console.log the `item` in the `renderItem`, it does not show anything in the console (not even an empty array). Where did my data go that I submitted into the `data` prop?

Should be obvious, but nothing is printed in that `<Text>` tag.

EDIT: Whole class added

```
class VideoFeed extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //this.dataRef = database.ref("music");
        this.state = {
            itemList: null,
        }
        //this.listenForMusic = this.listenForMusic.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.listenForMusic(); 
    }

    listenForMusic(){
        var dataRef = database.ref("music");
        let items = [];
        dataRef.orderByChild("date").on('child_added', (snap) => {
            items.push({
                videoURL: snap.val().youtubeURL,
                title: snap.val().title,
                thumbnail: snap.val().thumbnail
            });
        });
        this.setState({ itemList: items })
    }

    _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

    _renderVideoItem = ({item}) => (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                onPress={Actions.Submit}
            >
                <View style={styles.mediaContainer}>
                    <Image 
                        source={{uri: item.thumbnail }}
                        style={styles.mediaThumbnail}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.mediaMetaContainer}>
                        <View style={styles.topMetaContainer}>
                            <Text style={styles.mediaTitle}>
                                {item.title}
                            </Text>
                            <Text style={styles.sharedByUser}>
                            UNCVRD
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.bottomMetaContainer}>
                            <Icon
                                name='youtube-play'
                                type='material-community'
                                color='#ff0000'
                                size={16}
                            />
                            <View style={styles.bottomRightContainer}>
                                <Icon
                                    name='thumb-up'
                                    size={12}
                                    color='#aaa'
                                />
                                <Text style={styles.metaLikeCounter}>
                                    16
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.itemList);
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.itemList}
                    renderItem={({item}) => { console.log(item); return (<Text>{item.title}</Text>) }}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

---

EDIT 2: So I did an interesting test, I made two state variables: `realList` and `fakeList`:

```
state = { 
    realList: [],
    fakeList: [],
}
```

Then when the page will load, the following function is run that populates arrays called `real` and `fake`. One with data pulled from Firebase, the other hardcoded with array information:

```
listenForMusic = () => {
        var dataRef = database.ref("music");
        let real = [];
        let fake = [];
        dataRef.orderByChild("date").on('child_added', (snap) => {
            var url = snap.val().youtubeURL;
            var vidTitle = snap.val().title;
            var thumb = snap.val().thumbnail;
            real.push({
                videoURL: url,
                title: vidTitle,
                thumbnail: thumb
            });
        });
        fake.push({videoURL: "https://youtu.be/AHukwv_VX9A", title: "MISSIO - Everybody Gets High (Audio)", thumbnail: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AHukwv_VX9A/hqdefault.jpg"}, {videoURL: "https://youtu.be/G-yWpz0xkWY", title: "SMNM - Million ft. Compulsive", thumbnail: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/G-yWpz0xkWY/hqdefault.jpg"});
        this.setState({ 
            realList: real,
            fakeList: fake
        });
    }
```

Then I `console.log` both of the arrays after the render function and I see this:

[image]

And opening both:

[image]

So my question is, why does the "real" array look empty but still has data populated inside while the "fake" array displays that it holds two objects inside of it, even before we take a look inside??

Comment: Try to bind the listenForMusic function in the constructor like this: this.listenForMusic = this.listenForMusic.bind(this);

Comment: No, not in componentWillMount... in the constructor

Comment: @JanickFischer not sure if you saw my other comment, but I forgot to remove parentheses off listenformusic. However, the page loads but the list view doesnt display

Comment: oh trying that @JanickFischer one sec

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
renderItem={({item}) => return (<Text>{item.videoURL}</Text>)}
```

should be:

```
renderItem={(item) => return (<Text>{item.videoURL}</Text>)}
```

The way you have it now is trying to deconstruct a property called `item`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that did not change anything. The list still does not render :/

Comment: Did you remove the `{}`? So you have: `renderItem={(item) ... blah`?

Comment: yea :/ copy pasted your suggestion but removed the text `return` @Colin

Comment: Can you update your whole code in your question please?

Comment: sure, check out the edit above. The only thing missing is my Home class that calls `<VideoFeed />` once. I can throw in the dummy array provided in React Native docs as data and have it render to screen properly (just FYI)

Comment: You're still not binding `listenForMusic`?

Comment: in the constructor? I tried that and it made no difference. You're saying to do `this.listenForMusic = this.listenForMusic.bind(this)` right?

Comment: No, bind it as an arrow function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169744/discussion-between-jordan-lewallen-and-colin).

Comment: And you still have `{}` in your `renderItem`

Comment: Observed something very interesting. when you have some free time today, check out my second edit to the original question.

Comment: I would move your renderItem out from an arrow function to a function/const outside the render function. This way you only create one renderItem function.